# Could someone explain the code as follows?

Tags: java

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class PingPongMapMain {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        boolean odd;
        switch (args.length < 1 ? "usage" : args[0].toLowerCase()) {
            case "odd":
                odd = true;
                break;
            case "even":
                odd = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("Usage: java PingPongMain [odd|even]");
                return;        
        }
        int runs = 10000000;
        long start = 0;
        System.out.println("Waiting for the other odd/even");
        File counters = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),"counters.deleteme");        
        counters.deleteOnExit();
        try (FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(counters, "rw").getChannel()) {
        MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1024);
        long address = ((DirectBuffer) mbb).address();
        for (int i = -1; i < runs; i++) {
            for (; ; ) {
                long value = UNSAFE.getLongVolatile(null, address);
                boolean isOdd = (value & 1) != 0;
                if (isOdd != odd)
                    // wait for the other side.
                    continue;
                    // make the change atomic, just in case there is more than one odd/even process
                if (UNSAFE.compareAndSwapLong(null, address, value, value + 1))
                    break;
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.println("Started");
                start = System.nanoTime();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("... Finished, average ping/pong took %,d ns%n",
            (System.nanoTime() - start) / runs);
    }

   static final Unsafe UNSAFE;
   static {
        try {
            Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
            UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

> This example shows "Thread safe access to direct memory", and it used for share data between processes.When run this in two programs, one with odd and the other with even. you can see that each process is changing data via  persisted shared memory.

But I am confused about a few things:

1. what does the tmp file used for;
2. what does UnSafe used for here;
3. why unsafe use here;
4. why cast a field to a UnSafe type but not sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe()?

Comment: 5. What research did you do so far? 6. How do _you_ understand that code? (We might then be able to address misconceptions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program illustrates how two separate Java processes can communicate via a shared memory segment implemented via a memory mapped file.   One process makes a number at a location in the shared segment odd, and the other makes it even ... repeatedly ... "ping pong-ing" between the two processes.

> what does the tmp file used for

It effectively provides a way for two processes to share a memory segment.  A file is created, and mapped into the address spaces of two processes.  The net result is that the two processes are sharing the same area of memory.

> what does UnSafe used for here;

```
    long value = UNSAFE.getLongVolatile(null, address);
```

Reads 64 bits from `address` with a read barrier; i.e. ensuring that it is reading from main memory (not cache memory)

```
    UNSAFE.compareAndSwapLong(null, address, value, value + 1));
```

Performs an atomic compare and swap.  If the value at `address` is `value`, then atomically change it to `value + 1`.

> why unsafe use here;

Because it is a good way<sup>1</sup> perform those low-level operations (with precisely those semantics.  (Things like Java primitive mutexes and `Lock` don't have specified "Java memory model" semantics when the threads using them are in separate processes.)

> why cast a field to a UnSafe type but not sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe()?

This is some nasty stuff designed to get around JVM restrictions.  If you just call `Unsafe.getUnsafe()` you will typically get a `SecurityException`.

Reference:

- [Guide to `sun.misc.Unsafe`](http://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe)

Just look the other way .....

---

<sup>1 - Possibly the only way apart from writing non-portable native code.   But bear in mind that the `Unsafe` class is designed for JVM internal use, and the API and behavior *could* change without any notice.</sup>